# IE & Chrome scroll bar interferring with menu navigation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've written a simple HTML CSS nav menu position:fixed for a site. 
The menu drop-downs are set to overflow-y:scroll and the child uls are next to the parents
(see http://www.goodskiguide.com/gsgs-complete-a-z-resorts-guide/)

The scroll bar doesn't interfere in firefox as it only appears when you're actually scrolling but in Chrome & IE it's always there so when you navigate the cursor to the right to select a child li the hover attributes are lost.

Can anyone suggest how I might fix this. If the fix enplyos jQuery then please can you give details as I'm not quite thee with my jQ knowledge as yet.

Thanks

Comment: I have no problem on Chrome...

Comment: You mean the resort search? For me, in Firefox (Win 7, FF 29 nightly) the scrollbars are always there. Hovering over a scrollbar while trying to reach a sub-menu makes it all disappear.

Comment: I'm not sure if you looked before or after I removed the search but it's now on www.goodskiguide.com/testpost-2

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it works on your version of chrome, although for me, nope. And not IE either. Can't have websites that only work on some browsers. Unfortunately we have to cater for the difficulties of IE. 

Olly- I found on firefox if you stop scroll, pause a sec then scroll bar disappears and then you can move across with ease. But with other browsers the scroll bar is always there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simple sort of solution. The solution is basically to set the the padding-left of the container that is usually on the other side of the scroll bar to something close to the width of the scroll bar like this

```
ul{padding-left:30px;}  //or whatever the width of the scroll bar is
```

So that should effectively create a transparent left end that covers the scroll bar so that when the mouse hovers over the scroll bar, it's actually hovering over the content on the other side of the scrol bar, hence keeping it stiill hovered on.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8nbw/) showing the sample, it worked for me in chrome, IE and firefox